# Controlling a Minecraft server with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minecraft

I have a website I am running in rails. This is for testing and learning nothing fancy or that will have a lot traffic. I am running a minecraft server for friends and was wanting to create a rails app to interact with it. Just Because. My question is what would be the best way to do this. Once you start minecraft server it runs until you kill it. All log information is shown on the server screen as you play. You can type in commands on the server as well to control the world. So what I want is a way to record new info put out by server and log in the database as well as send new commands. If this is hard that is fine im just looking for experience.

Comment: it sounds like you just want to ssh into your server and run `$ rails c` to bring up the rails console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Minecraft server has output on both the `stdout` and `stderr`. It also takes input from `stdin`. For more information on Standard streams read the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams) article.

The project you're speaking of is pretty advanced, and requires knowledge Unix processes and threading.

Typically, your program would need to:

- create streams for `stdout`, `stderr` and `stdin` to streams which your program has a handle over
- `fork`

Then in the child process:

- redirect `stdout`, `stdin` and `stderr` to the created streams
- `exec` the Minecraft server

In the parent:

- start a thread that listens to the Minecraft server `stdout` and `stderr`
- start a thread that listens for `stdin` and can interact with the Minecraft server
- optionally, all the communication *to* the Minecraft server should be done inside it's own thread

If you're just starting out with Ruby/Rails or the other technologies mentioned this can be intimidating. A few years ago I wrote [Tartar](https://github.com/gmalette/tartar), a Rails application that does essentially what you're looking to do. I suggest having a look, perhaps it can help you get started. I would start in the `minecraft:start` rake task. Note that this was 2 years ago and it may not be compatible with the Minecraft server anymore.

**NOTE:** This will not work on Windows.

Comment: This is perfect thanks for the answer. yes this is intimidating but how else will I learn. Again just the answer I was looking for thanks.